# FT232R USB IC with direct access IO (no UART)

Tags: com, serial-port, usb, uart

I would like to create a scenario to directly access IOs via USB by using FT232R.
In more detail, scenario is the following: I would like to feed an LIN transceiver IC by a FT232R USB device. However, the FT232R as a USB-serial-converter outputs UART signals, which includes a start bit as well as a stop bit. For me, it is required to not have these start and stop bits, even though they are standardized in UART protocol.

My questions:
Is it possible to use the bang mode of this device to avoid start/stop bits and transfer raw data? Then, how to program the code for doing this?
If not, are there any USB transceiver, which have to possibility via COM/driver access to fulfil my requirement?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the chip provides 4 pins that can be used for generic bit banging.  Here is an [application note](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_232R-01_Bit_Bang_Mode_Available_For_FT232R_and_Ft245R.pdf) describing how to use bit banging mode.